# How do I limit the amount of RAM that WINE sees?

Tags: wine, ram

I have a program that I want to use but it's very old and measures RAM in Kilobytes. It won't start because it complains that it can't run with less than 5000K RAM (even though I have vastly more). How do I limit the amount of RAM that WINE sees / tells the programs about?

Comment: What program exactly? And why do you think that by reducing the amount of memory WINE can use will work? The program is not recognizing the memory as it is.

Comment: Whatever it recognizes, that's what I want to reduce. I want the program to think that my computer actually has X amount of RAM.

Comment: That won't make any difference. Some very old software simply cannot run on newer hardware, not even natively, let alone emulated. It's a waste of time, I'll leave you to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but I found a script [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process#answer-279175) that limits the memory of a process.

The script is as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]
then
        echo Usage: `basename $0` "<limit> <command>..."
        exit 1
fi

limit="$1"
shift

cgname="limitmem_$$"
echo "limiting memory to $limit (cgroup $cgname) for command $@" >&2

cgm create memory "$cgname" >/dev/null
cgm setvalue memory "$cgname" memory.limit_in_bytes "$limit" >/dev/null
# try also limiting swap usage, but this fails if the system has no swap
cgm setvalue memory "$cgname" memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes "$limit" >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
bytes_limit=`cgm getvalue memory "$cgname" memory.limit_in_bytes | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d\"`

# spawn subshell to run in the cgroup
# set +e so a failing child does not prevent us from removing the cgroup
set +e
(
set -e
cgm movepid memory "$cgname" `sh -c 'echo $PPID'` > /dev/null
exec "$@"
)

# grab exit code 
exitcode=`echo $?`

set -e

peak_mem=`cgm getvalue memory "$cgname" memory.max_usage_in_bytes | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d\"`
failcount=`cgm getvalue memory "$cgname" memory.failcnt | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d\"`
percent=`expr "$peak_mem" / \( "$bytes_limit" / 100 \)`
echo "peak memory used: $peak_mem ($percent%); exceeded limit $failcount times" >&2

cgm remove memory "$cgname" >/dev/null

exit $exitcode
```

You'll have to install `cgmanager` (`sudo apt-get install cgmanager`), but it's little more than half of a megabyte.

It's possible WINE (or the executable) will detect all the RAM you have, despite the limit, in which case this will most likely fail. If that happens, you can always delete the script and then uninstall `cgmanager` with a quick `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge cgmanager`.

Comment: `call to cgmanager_create_sync failed: invalid request` for every process I try to run with `limitmem 100M processname`

Comment: I've personally never used it, it just seemed simple. Maybe one of the other suggestions will work.